# QT widget How to get RGB Buffer from QCamera

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qcamera

I am porting an video streamer application to QT (from HTML), I just had the webcam working using QT, and now I want to know How can I get the RGB Video buffer from a QT Camera? All the samples I can see is capturing image to a file.

I am using QT Widgets and not QML since its a desktop application.
What I am trying to do is to get the buffer image of the camera, compress it and send to network.
And I want to trigger this manualy since I want to call the capture of next frame when all the compression and sending is done to prevent timing issue.